# Why would I do a typecheck (===) when using typeof-operator

Tags: javascript

In many examples of code I do see people using `===` when typechecking with `typeof`.
But `typeof` always returns a `string`. No matter which variable you are checking. So why typechecking this by using `===`?

Example:

```
if(typeof num === 'number')
    // do something
```

Is there any edge-case I dont know?

Comment: I think it's usually just a practice people like to follow in all situations to keep themselves aware of it. If novice coders saw "==" too much, they might assume "===" doesn't matter and use the easier one.

Comment: You know the difference between "==" and "==="?

Comment: @ user3355243: from his post, seems he does - he is pointing that typeof always returns a string, therefore there are not "dangers" of bad casts and so - and thus, apparently, no need to worry using == instead of ===. This is what he asks.

Comment: People do not like to use logic, for typeof comparison two equals is enough, people use === as default without trying to put a bit of effort of thinking if it makes sense, it is the other edge of comparisons.  So your logic is totally ok, for typeof two equals are enough, you do not need to worry for any edge case.

Comment: @Daniel Aranda: people probably spend their effort thinking about more important matters than deciding when the `==` operator won't harm them. ;)

Comment: Fair point @PieterWitvoet. I would say that some "best practices" are just really "mind shortcuts" to skip some reasoning. Problem is when you try to chat with people about logic and they use a "best practice" as a logical argument. Bests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) always returns a string, so the behavior will be identical. If you don't specifically need coercion, it's good practice to use the strictest available operator.

There shouldn't be a performance difference in this case, as typeof is guaranteed to return a string, so no coercion should ever be done. If someone changes the code, however, using `===` will force the new code to also return a string (or make them update the condition).

The `==` operator is useful when you need to compare two values of different (or potentially different) types, but if you *know* ahead of time the types will be identical, `===` has all the benefits and enforces strict comparison. Later on, if someone wants to make the code less strict, they have to explicitly do so.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's exactly what I answered. You use `===` because the behavior is identical, so best practices say use the strict option (and change later *if* you need looser semantics).

Answer (score -1):

If there is no type conversion possible in a given comparison (which there is not with `typeof x === "string"` because `typeof` always returns a string), then there is no functional difference between `==` and `===`.  Which to use in that case is more a matter of preferred style since there is no functional difference.

So, in your case of:

```
if (typeof num === 'number')
```

there is no functional difference between that and the `==` version:

```
if (typeof num == 'number')
```

Either will provide the exact same result no matter what value `num` has.  You can use either version and your code will run correctly in all cases.

> Is there any edge-case I dont know?

No, there are no edge cases for this particular example.

---

> So why typechecking this by using ===?

One popular recommendation for Javascript coding is to always use `===` unless you explicitly WANT a type conversion to be allowed.  This is considered a safer coding style because you won't accidentally get a type conversion that you weren't thinking about or planning for.

So, if you are following this recommendation, then you get yourself in a frame of mind that your default coding style is to use `===` unless there is a reason NOT to use it (e.g. you want a type conversion to be allowed).

That is the opposite of your logic where you are looking for a reason to use `===` instead of looking for a reason not to use `==`.

Comment: You may want to add in the reason why `===` is preferred over `==`, see my answer.

Comment: @LarsEbert - I added info about `===`, but it appeared the OP already knows about the type conversion difference with `===`.  They were asking why should someone use `if (typeof x === "string")` when that's a case where no type conversion could ever happen.

Answer (score -1):

**`===` is usually faster than `==`.**

If you compare two values while ignoring their their type (`==`), javascript usually has to convert one or both of the values to another type internally and do additional checks.

`===` on the other hand does not have to convert anything and only has to do one comparison. So when you do not have to worry about cases like `"1" == 1`, `===` is usually faster.

In this case, as `typeof` always returns a string and the second value also is a string, `==` is not needed, so `===` is uses out of convention.

Comment: "*usually*", yes. But not in this specific case, where the compiler does already know that both operands are of the same (string) type.

Comment: `===` *can be* faster when coercion is actually involved, but this is comparing a value guaranteed to be a string with a string literal.

Comment: This micro optimization will never gonna be the main reason.